# Can I have my website run on an old version of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, version

I have an old web application that was written in classic asp and javascript. The application was built in the time of Internet Explorer 6 and 7. I believe that was written in Javascript version 1.3.

The web app works fine in IE emulators but it terrible in anything later than IE 7. Other than using emulators is there any way that I can use javascript 1.3 through the web pages? I don't intend to try to change every users browser configurations, so that's not an option.

I can make jQuery work but that would be a lot of rewritting.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bite the bullet and get it rewritten. It could be some really simple issues that cause it to not run.

Comment: start with the errors you get in the console. it might be a few simple changes

Comment: Unfortunately there is a LOT of javascript. It's not just simple validations. The pages average 1000 to 2000 lines of code. The ASP seems to just be used for database interation, html for simple presentation and everything else is javascript. I agree with epascarello, but I dread doing it.

Comment: Even if you have 1M lines of javascript, it might be only 1 line that cause you the trouble. It can obviously be a long-term project, but it can also be a 5 minutes solution.

Comment: I understand the possibility of a small correction over a huge correction. What I was actually getting at is that we have an old application that works with old libraries with no changes needed. I just wanted to know if there is any way to use an old version of javascript in a new/modern browser.